# Recording USB mouse events

Tags: winapi, usb, mouseevent

What is the best way to capture and record the global USB mouse events in Windows? I have already written a small data capture program using a [low level mouse callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However, this is not low-level enough for me: this approach allows you to capture the position of the mouse cursor on the screen (i.e. screen coordinate) rather than capturing the actual mouse events which are in fact relative motion (think delta-x and delta-y).

I could look at the position increment at each event but since screen coordinates are clipped between 0 and screen width/height, some data is lost. Also, I have no idea what happens if a full-screen program like a game changes the screen resolution or do something else that might affect the mouse events.

So is there any other user-mode method to record the USB mouse event at a lower level than the `SetWindowsHookEx` hooks? I want to get to the physical mouse events before any processing by Windows.

Comment: Next step down is a USB filter driver so you can see the low-level traffic.  Takes about a year of your life to learn the driver programming skills.  Not exactly worth the feature, but you'll of course know a lot more about USB and drivers when you're done.  You however can't get help with that here.

Comment: @HansPassant Writing a device drivers is exactly what I hope to avoid! I have some experience with that but it has been many years and all I remember is that was such a complex world.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since nobody else has answered, I just report what I have have found out so far. As far as I have learned, there are at least 5 ways to record mouse data in Windows:

1. The [LowLevelMouseProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call back mechanism. The limitation of this approach is that it reports the position of mouse cursor on the screen, rather than the raw data received from the mouse. It means that data has been already processed.
2. The [raw input API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to capture raw data sent from mouse (or any other HID device).
3. [DirectInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416842%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) allows you to capture raw mouse and keyboard (as well as other devices) data with minimal delay. Situation with DirectInput is a bit confusing as it is an old API and the new API replacing it, the XInput does not support all [devices the older one did](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectInput).
4. The [event tracing API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which allows you to capture kernel-level ETW traces in a user-mode program.
5. Writing a KMDF filter device driver to capture the mouse USB traffic at lowest level.

The last solution is the most complex and most powerful one. There are few commercial applications that actually do that (and more!). An example is BusHound.

I'm not so sure about the 4th solution (ETW approach). Apparently it works best with the recent versions of Windows. I couldn't find any example program that does something similar to what I have in my mind (i.e. recording raw mouse events). Also, it seems to be complex enough that even a simple test program would need considerable effort to write. At the end, I don't know it will let me get the actual mouse reports or not.

The 2nd solution, the raw input API is surprisingly easy to use. I could write a simple program to use it in just a few hours. However, it has a big limitation: it is based on a WM_INPUT message sent to the application's window. If timing is critical, which in my case is, this approach is limited as the message loop of the application processes messages sequentially. Thus the delay from the time the mouse events are captured by the USB port till the time the appropriate message handler gets called is not fixed or even bounded.

All in all, I did not come up with any easy answer to the question.